# How to trigger a pull request job in Jenkins based on Github's changed files?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

I'm trying to configure an automated pull-request job triggering in a monorepo concluded from several subdirectories. This means I need to run a specific pipeline per subdirectory, and not run unnecessary ones.

What I have already tried:

1. [Github Pull Request Builder plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin) - Which is a great plugin for those who are not running a scripted pipeline, but rather a "Classic" Jenkins project. Also, it is no longer supported and many issues remain unanswered there.
2. [Git SCM Jenkins Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) - which has a promising feature of `includedRegions` and `excludedRegions`, and is supposed to trigger jobs based on a regular expression. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected and [triggers builds on any changes](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23606).
3. Using the Git changeset that Jenkins receives, perform a `Validate stage` when build starts, and if none of the changed files starts with the required subdirectory - abort and exit the build. This results in tens of aborted unnecessary builds.
4. [Jenkins Generic Webhook Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) - This plugin is a simple to use plugin that relies on the json payload it receives in a webhook, and triggers a job based on a defined filter. The problem is that in Github's API, pull request opened/updated events do not include the changed files. So this use case only works with Github's "push" event, but not specifically with PR events.

I want the flow to work this way:

1. A developer opens a pull request in Github. His/hers changes are related to a subdirectory in a monorepo called `APP1/`.
2. Jenkins receives a notification (or a webhook of some sort) and triggers a job that builds and tests `APP1`.
3. Jenkins sends the build/test result back to the pull request checks view (I've got this stage covered).

Comment: Would be interested to know where you got to with this as it's bugging me too.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, we eventually decided to stop using monorepos and moved to single repo per app.. (not only due to the above problem)